# Windows 7 Virtual Machine Error "Not enough storage is available to process this command."

Tags: virtual-machine, network-shares, microsoft-virtual-pc

When I try to access my host machine (Win 7 Ent) from two different virtual machines (both Win 7 Pro) using an UNC path and I keep getting "Not enough storage is available to process this command." Ironically, that same host machine with two other virtual machines (both Win XP) using an UNC path just fine. This just started happening about 2 hours ago.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem occur with 2 physical PCs on my network. I fixed it by changing the value of IRPStackSize, as suggested in these articles:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106167

http://winhlp.com/node/40

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical behavior of server that starts lots of app compiled with Delphi.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507853/system-error-code-8-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command/10560659#10560659) post.